# Extracting values from USGS real time water service

Tags: javascript, jquery

There must be something simple I am missing, but alas, I do not know what I do not know. Below is the code I have thus far for trying to get current streamflow conditions from the USGS.

```
// create site object
function Site(siteCode) {

    this.timeSeriesList = [];
    this.siteCode = siteCode;
    this.downloadData = downloadData;
    this.getCfs = getCfs;

    // create reference to the local object for use inside the jquery ajax function below
    var self = this;

    // create timeSeries object
    function TimeSeries(siteCode, variableCode) {
        this.variableCode = variableCode;
        this.observations = [];
    }

    // create observation object
    function TimeSeriesObservation(stage, timeDate) {
        this.stage = stage;
        this.timeDate = timeDate;
    }

    // include the capability to download data automatically
    function downloadData() {

        // construct the url to get data
        // TODO: include the capability to change the date range, currently one week (P1W)
        var url = "http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?format=json&sites=" + this.siteCode + "&period=P1W&parameterCd=00060,00065"

        // use jquery getJSON to download the data
        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {

            // timeSeries is a two item list, one for cfs and the other for feet
            // iterate these and create an object for each
            $(data.value.timeSeries).each(function () {

                // create a timeSeries object
                var thisTimeSeries = new TimeSeries(
                    self.siteCode,

                    // get the variable code, 65 for ft and 60 for cfs
                    this.variable.variableCode[0].value
                );

                // for every observation of the type at this site
                $(this.values[0].value).each(function () {

                    // add the observation to the list
                    thisTimeSeries.observations.push(new TimeSeriesObservation(

                        // observation stage or level
                        this.value,

                        // observation time
                        this.dateTime
                    ));
                });

                // add the timeSeries instance to the object list
                self.timeSeriesList.push(thisTimeSeries);
            });
        });
    }

    // return serialized array of cfs stage values
    function getCfs() {

        // iterate timeseries objects
        $(self.timeSeriesList).each(function () {

            // if the variable code is 00060 - cfs
            if (this.variableCode === '00060') {

                // return serialized array of stages
                return JSON.stringify(this.observations);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I simply access the object directly using the command line, I can access individual observations using:

```
> var watauga = new Site('03479000')
> watauga.downloadData()
> watauga.timeSeriesList[0].observations[0]
```

I can even access all the reported values with the timestamps using:

```
> JSON.stringify(watauga.timeSeriesList[0].observations)
```

Now I am trying to wrap this logic into the getCfs function, with little success. What am I missing?

Comment: The first thing you're missing is a description of the error--what does "little success" mean? The second thing I notice is that `getCfs()` assumes that the data has been downloaded. If you are not waiting for the data to be downloaded, you may be attempting to iterate on an unpopulated `timeSeriesList`.

Comment: I'm not sure how to respond @Palpatim. It is not an error, simply undefined when running watauga.getCfs(). You are correct, downloadData does have to be run first, but it is responding with undefined even when I can access specific singular observations and even all observations using the code samples above. Hence, the values exist, but I just cannot seem to access them. Thus no, there is no question. The data has been downloaded. I have verified the data has been downloaded using the interactive commands above. Still, getCfs returns undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real issue, I discovered through just starting over from scratch on this function, is something wrong with my implementation of `jQuery.().each()`. My second stab at the issue, I successfully used a standard `for in` loop. Here is the working code.

```
function getCfs() {
    for (var index in this.timeSeriesList) {
        if (this.timeSeriesList[index].variableCode === '00060'){
            return JSON.stringify(this.timeSeriesList[index].observations);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, some of the stuff you are talking about @Palpatim, I definitely will have to look into. Thank you for pointing out these considerations. This looks like a good time to further investigate these promises things.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in the code above that enforces the data being downloaded. Maybe in whatever execution path you're using to call `getCfs()` you have a wait or a loop that checks for the download to complete prior to calling `getCfs()`, but if you're simply calling

```
site.downloadData();
site.getCfs()
```

you're almost certainly not finished loading when you call `site.getCfs()`.

You'd need to do invoke a callback from within your `success` handler to notify the caller that the data is downloaded. For example, change the signature of `Site.downloadData` to

```
function downloadData(downloadCallback) {
// ...
```

Add a call to the `downloadCallback` after you're finished processing the data:

```
// After the `each` that populates 'thisTimeSeries', but before you exit 
// the 'success' handler
if (typeof downloadCallback === 'function') {
    downloadCallback();
}
```

And then your invocation would be something like:

```
var watauga = new Site('03479000');
var downloadCallback = function() {
    watauga.timeSeriesList[0].observations[0];
};
watauga.downloadData(downloadCallback);
```

That way, you're guaranteed that the data is finished processing before you attempt to access it.

If you're getting an `undefined` in some other part of your code, of course, then there may be something else wrong. Throw a debugger on it and step through the execution. Just bear in mind that interactive debugging has many of the same problems as interactively calling the script; the script has time to complete its download in the background before you start inspecting the variables, which makes it look like everything's hunky dory, when in fact a non-interactive execution would have different timing.